# How can I print in decimal form, binary numbers with 1000 bits?

Tags: binary, type-conversion, numbers

I have numbers with several hundred of decimal digits stored in binary form in arrays (appr. 1000 bits, 10^300). How can I print these numbers in decimal form? The standard way to convert from bin to dec with div 10 and mod 10 are hard to implement. I'm using C/C++.

Answer (score 0):

- create an array of integer64 with length = 1000
- calculate the decimal value of the bits one by one
- save them in the array
- add the array rows

For example: 25 = 11001
The array should contain following values: [16, 8, 0, 0, 1]

```
2^4*1:    1 6
2^3*1:      8
2^2*0:      0
2^1*0:      0
2^0*1:      1
+         (1)  
          2 5
```

This method should work without mod or div (tested in python3 up to 2^1000).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I don't quite follow you. The value an integer64 can hold is max 2^63. This is the largest value C can handle. How do you mean I can calculate e.g. 2^100? Maybe Python can, but not C. With big numbers (in an array) I have to print each decimal digit separately. In your example I have to print first "2" and then "5". How do I get these digits?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, my first answer was not that understandable. So I programmed the converter in Rust (the closest language to C I know). I hope that makes it a bit more clear.

```
use rand::Rng;

fn pow_(num: i64, exp: i64) -> (f64, i64) {
    let mut e: i64 = 0;
    let mut current = num as f64;
    for i in 0..(exp - 1){
        current *= num as f64;
        if current / 10.0 > 1.0{
            current /= 10.0;
            e += 1;
        }
    }
    (current, e)
}

fn rand_bit_array(l: usize) -> Vec<bool>{
    let mut ba = Vec::with_capacity(l);
    let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();
    ba.push(true);
    for _ in 1..l{
        ba.push(rng.gen_bool(0.5));
    }
    ba
}

fn add(ba: Vec<bool>){
    println!("{:?}", ba);
    let (mut out, e) = pow_(2, ba.len() as i64);

    // round to the first 30 numbers
    for i in 1..30{
        if ba[i] {
            let dec = pow_(2, ba.len() as i64 - i as i64);
            out += dec.0 / 10.0_f64.powf((e - dec.1) as f64);
        }
    }
    println!("Result: {} * 10 ^ {}", out, e);
}

fn main() {
    println!("Result: {} * 10 ^ {}", pow_(2, 1000).0, pow_(2, 1000).1);
    add(rand_bit_array(1000));
}
```

Explanation:

- pow_           - power up to 2^1000 easily
- rand_bit_array - generates a random bit array
- add_           - calculates the decimal number

Example Output:

```
[true, true, false, false, true, true, true, false, false, false, ...]  (1000 Elements)  
Result: 1.7247795190143262 * 10 ^ 301
```

Comment: Thanks for your code. I have checked Rust briefly, it seems to me a smart language! There are some things in the code I don't understand. This line: 
out += dec.0 / 10.0_f64.powf((e - dec.1) as f64); 
is a bit complex. As I understand "out" is a f64 variable where you accumulate the value. f64 holds 53 significant bits (17-18 decimal digits). Your output is 17 digits. How will your code look to output e.g. 50 digits?

Comment: "How will your code look to output e.g. 50 digits?" - It wont. The output is just an aproximation of the whole number. The single numbers which are added are already rounded in the pow_ function. The maximal accuracy should be these 17 decimal digits.